# How can I get the root view for making a Snackbar when class inherits from Application?

Tags: android, static, android-view, android-snackbar

I have a class that inherits from Application so I cannot use findViewById.
The snackbar should show, when the app is launching, so my approach was to get the root view of my launching activity and make a static method like:

```
public static RelativeLayout GetRootViewOfLaunchingActivity() { return root; }
```

Then in my class inheriting from application I did this:

```
public void onGetRegisteredResult(DJIError error)
{
            // SDK REGISTRATION SUCCES
            if(error == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS)
            {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    // Show snackbar with success message
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Snackbar.make(LaunchingActivity.GetRootViewOfLaunchingActivity(), R.string.sdk_success, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.d("SDK REGISTRATION", "DJI SDK registered");
                DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
            }
}
```

I mean it works just fine but I don't feel like this is the prettiest solution because I need to make the root view of my launching activity static, so my question is can anyone tell me a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get it - why you can't use `findViewById` if you inherit from `Activity`? Typo in question

Comment: yes, this was a typo, title should have made it clear :) but thanks, i fixed it

Comment: How `onGetRegisteredResult` affect application UX? I mean if there is an error - does application hangs or just show `snackbar` and that it?

Comment: `onGetRegisteredResult` is a callback and will be executed once the dji sdk is registerd. but this method has nothing to do with my question. there could be any other method making a `snackbar`. perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough. All I want to know is which View should I use as argument when I call the `make(View view, CharSequence text, int duration)` method from `snackbar` when my class that wants to use this method extends `Application` and has no View or `fiendViewById` method